# MS SQL Server 2008 R2 -- Install and Configuration

Tags: sql-server, configuration, jdbc

I'm trying to install and configure SQL Server 2008 R2 for use with a Java-based application.
I've installed SQL Server and setup an empty database instance.
I created a user and assigned it to the instance.
I'm using 'Mixed' authentication.

When the application tries to connect, I see the error:

```
apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect)
```

My JDBC connection string is:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/dbinstance
```

The driver is:

```
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

When I run netstat -a -n -o, I expected to see port 1433 being listened to, but I didn't show up.

I went into SQL Server Configuration Manager and explicitly set the IPAll TCP Port to 1433 and restarted the server.  But port 1433 still doesn't show up and the connect from the application failed.  Instead when I look at the server log, I see port 49806:

```
Server is listening on [127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 49806]
```

Which seems strange to me.  I'm not sure where 49806 is picked up from.  I also see 49806 via netstat, but not port 1433.

I tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in the connect string, but that didn't help.
I also tried changing port 1433 to 49806 in the connect string, but it didn't help either.
I also tried connecting as user 'sa', but no luck.

I must have done something wrong in the install, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Did You try to connect to it with SQL Server Management Studio? (You need to install workstation components to have it installed)

Comment: Yes.  I can connect, but only when  I use ./SQLServer.  When I use localhost, it won't connect from Management Studio.

Comment: SQLServer was the 'instance' name that I used during the install.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious or your connection string tries to connect to dbinstance instead of SQLServer?

Comment: OK.  I got it. Thanks for the question, Filip.  I found in SQL Server Configuration Manager that under TCP/IP settings in the Protocols tab that TCP/IP is not enabled by default.  I turned that on and restarted the server.  Now I can connect using 'localhost' and port 1433 is showing up correctly in the server log and with netstat.  And the connection is working.

Comment: @GeorgeHernando Care to add as an answer so it can be closed.